# For $n>1$, let $H$ be the set of all products in $S_n$ of a multiple of four transpositions. Show $H=A_n$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

I'm reading *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition),"* by Gallian.

This is Exercise 5.80 *ibid.* **Answers that use only tools available in the textbook so far are preferred.**

> For $n>1$, let $H$ be the set of all permutations in $S_n$ that can be expressed as a product of a multiple of four transpositions. Show that $H=A_n$.

This is a proof verification question (plus $\varepsilon>0$).

### My Attempt:

Well, my first observation is that $e=(12)(12)(12)(12)\in H$.

For any $\sigma\in H$, by definition, $\sigma$ is a product of a multiple of four transpositions; in particular, each multiple of four is even; so $\sigma\in A_n$. Hence $H\subseteq A_n$.

If $\alpha\in A_n$ is a product of $t$ transpositions with $t\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, then $\alpha=e\alpha=(12)(12)\alpha\in H$.

If $\beta\in A_n$ is a product of a multiple of four transpositions, then there is nothing to prove; $\beta\in H$.

Thus, since any $\tau\in A_n$ is by definition an even product of transpositions and products of a number in either class of even numbers modulo four are in $H$, we have $\tau\in H$. Hence $A_n\subseteq H$.

Hence $H=A_n$. $\square$

---

Another idea is to prove that $H$, as a subset of $A_n$, is also a subgroup of $A_n$. I'd use the "one step subgroup lemma" since I already have that $H$ is nonempty. (But how?) It would then be a matter of showing $\lvert H\rvert=\lvert A_n\rvert$. (But again, how?)

Please help :)

Comment: When you say, “another idea is to prove that $H$...is also a subgroup of $A_n$,” are you envisioning using the fact that $A_n$ is simple for $n \geq 5$?

Comment: @JordanGreen, No, I'm not that good! Besides, simple groups aren't covered in the textbook so far.

Comment: Looks like Gallian could make a good headline writer. For confused readers like me: "a multiple of four transpositions" means "[a multiple of four] many transpositions", not "a multiple of [four transpositions]". :P

Comment: Huh, then how would showing that $H$ is a subgroup of $A_n$ show that $H = A_n$?  Maybe I’m confused about your approach...

Comment: Oh, never mind.  I just saw the last sentence.  Sorry about not reading more carefully.  I don’t see how showing that $|A_n| = |H|$ would be any easier than showing that they are equal as sets.  In particular, your earlier proof of equality looks fine.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Well, I had to practice my journalese just to get the headline to fit . . .

Comment: For $e$, you could also say it's a product of 0 transpositions.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: I'd have thought that too had Gallian not used $e=(12)(12)$ so show $e\in A_n$ during, if I remember correctly, the proof that $A_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$. I suppose Gallian doesn't count $0$ as a natural number. I'm just keeping in the spirit of the textbook (because such restrictions might lead to greater creativity & fun).

Comment: Also note that if $n \ge 3$ (or $n \ge 4$ with the restriction of not using empty products), you can require no repeated transpositions appear right next to each other.  Then $e = (12)(34)(12)(34)$.  And for a product of $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ transpositions $\tau_1 \cdots \tau_n$, choose another transposition $\sigma$ not equal to either $\tau_1$ or $\tau_n$; then the product is also equal to $\sigma \tau_1^\sigma \cdots \tau_n^\sigma \sigma$ where $\tau_i^\sigma = \sigma \tau_i \sigma$ is the conjugate transposition.

Comment: Actually, for $n\ge 3$, you could also use $e=(12)(13)(12)(23)$.

Comment: Please would you elaborate on your comment with an answer, @JordanGreen? It's just so I can close the question :)